# Reformat my jQuery to select only p's under this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am coding an index for over 1000 titles.  I have 2 jsfiddles, one works, but it would take me forever to code all titles.  So I found a way to copy the index and covert it to html, but it is listed as all p's, and not sure if I am able to still get it working.  here is the fiddle and code for the working one. https://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/91d9zbtb/

```
    <div class="list-container">
 <!-- The A List -->
    <div class="title">
        <button>A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="title-contents">
        <li class="contents-description">
            <a href="#">50010 My first book</a>
        </li>       
          <p><strong>Class Code:</strong> 50010<br><strong>Author</strong>Jim Schwetz<br><strong>Note:</strong><br>The following shall be sold separately:<br>- COver<br>- Index</p>
        <li class="contents-description">
            <a href="#">50011 My second book</a>
        </li>
        <p><strong>Class Code:</strong><br><strong>Author:</strong>Me again<br><strong>Note:</strong><br>The following shall be sold separately<br>-  Steel backing<br>- Wire binding</p>       
    </div>    
<!-- The B List -->
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title-contents').hide();
  $('p').hide();
  $('.title').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.title-contents').fadeToggle(700);
  });
  $('.contents-description').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').fadeToggle(700);
  });
});
```

When I copy and paste the content and convert it to html, I get this https://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/ojn24b5o/2/  I added 2 classes for the first title, but I would have to add this to 1000 titles.

```
<p class="title">50010 title of My book</p>
<p class="title-contents"><strong>Class Code:</strong> 50010</p>
<p><strong>author</strong> me</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong></p>
<p>The following shall be sold separately:</p>
<ul>
<li>cover</li>
<li>index</li>
</ul>

<p>50011 title of My 2nd book- notice no class</p>
<p><strong>Class Code:</strong> 50011</p>
<p><strong>author</strong> me</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong></p>
<p>The following shall be sold separately:</p>
<ul>
<li>cover</li>
<li>index</li>
</ul>
```

and the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p:not(.title)').hide();
  $('li').hide();

  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.title-contents').fadeToggle(700);
  });
  $('.contents-description').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').fadeToggle(700);
  });


});
```

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid parent for `<li>`. It is very difficult to manipulate the DOM using invalid structure. Browsers may not render things the way you show them in the invalid markup

Comment: How are you converting this new html? What is the data source? If there is a way to wrap sections it would help tremendously...otherwise if the element structure is identical for each `section` it is feasible to work through this without manually adding classes

Comment: you have to be more specific on what you're trying to achieve and what is generating your html. But invalid structure should be corrected first.

Comment: http://www.html-cleaner.com/

Comment: I am copying the content from a pdf.  I did not want to convert pdf to html as it adds everything to code.  So I can copy the text and put it in this site above but it uses all p's.  I guess I can just keep using the other version I had and copy each title individually, just trying to save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to wrap each `section`. It also hides all but the title in the section and clicking title will toggle all the other elements in that section ( sort of accordion like)

```
var $ul = $('ul').hide()
// work from bottom up wrapping elements into sections
for (var i = $ul.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var list = $ul.eq(i)
    list.add(list.prevUntil('ul')).wrapAll('<div class="section">')
}
// work through sections adding behaviors 
$('.section').each(function(){   
  var $p= $(this).children('p').hide();
  $p.eq(0).show().addClass('title').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().toggle()
  });
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/924e6991/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks charliefl, I will try this now,  I did not think of that.

Comment: If structure is consistent it wouldn't take much to parse all this into json using jQuery and store in database

Comment: <https://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/ojn24b5o/2/>  Thanks,  that worked perfect.  The structure will come this way from using the converter, and knowing I should use a structure, converting it to html, and using your solution, I will have this 1000+ index done in 10 min's vs days.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question or the desired result, but if all of your markup will follow the same pattern listed above then I think you might be over-thinking the problem. Have you tried using a simple find-and-replace in your text editor to add the classes? For example, for the title class, you could search for:

```
"<p>5" and replace it with "<p class="title">5"
```

and for the title-contents class you could search for:

```
"<p><strong>Class Code:" and repleace it with "<p class="title-contents"><strong>Class Code:"
```

Of course I don't know the full-extent of your content so you would want to evaluate each instance and make sure that it follows the pattern, or tailor the pattern to suit it, but that would give you your desired class structure.

This assumes too that you do not need a dynamic solution, since you mentioned copy and paste.

And note, that this is not a programmatic solution, this is just a practical solution for a one-off scenario.

Comment: Yes I see where you are going with this, and this would work, faster than my other way.  I might try the solution from charlietfl first, and if that doesnt work, I will try your  idea.   Thanks